# My girlfriend's mother called the police to ban me from getting into the country

Tags: visas, uk, weddings

So I've been dating this girl for over a year now (she's from the uk) and we were planning on meeting and getting married so I could join her, but her mother had called the police and she says she's gonna call a lawyer and try to do everything she can to stop me from getting there (because she's so racist towards me) so my question is, can she actually do that? Especially that there's no proof that I'm involved in any crime activities or anything that normally gets you banned from getting into a country.

Comment: Under what permission are you entering the UK?

Comment: Is she a minor ? This might not be relevant but still then. Can she support herself financially ? After getting married do you want to settle in UK ? If yes then the question of financial support becomes an issue.

Comment: How often have you met before?  Does one of you intend to immigrate into the other's country?  Are there any facts about your circumstance that we should know?

Comment: She's 20 and she can support herself financially, we're dating online and agreed on meeting and getting married then I'd join her, but her mother had prevented her from visiting me and maybe she's gonna try to make it harder for me to get a visa if I wanted to go there, can she do that with no evidence of anything against me?

Comment: @Khaled She can't do anything. Your girlfriend is an adult. Calling a lawyer is an empty threat, since there's nothing any reputable solicitor could do. The police also won't care. If she keeps meddling in your girlfriend's life, your girlfriend can report her to the police for harassment.

Comment: @Khaled IMHO I doubt you need to worry about whether you’ll be banned based on a call by your prospective mother-in-law to Immigration. If you need your online ‘girlfriend’ to sponsor your visa application in any shape or form, rather than being able to prove that you are eligible and qualify IN YOUR OWN RIGHT, it’s highly unlikely that you’d be given any kind of visa based on a ‘relationship’ with someone you’ve never met in person. At the very least you’d need a history of her visiting you. And yes, your MIL can blow the whistle https://www.gov.uk/report-immigration-crime

Comment: Khaled -- you probably need to change your plans anyway.
As a **visitor** to the UK (so a normal visitor visa, or a visa-free entry from a country that is allowed that), you are **not allowed to get married in the UK**. And even once you are married, your partner needs to be earning at least £18,600 per year, and that is due to go up soon.

Answer (score 15):

> can she actually do that?

Of course she can. Anyone call the police for anything. The more relevant question is "what happens if she does?"

That really depends on the details: what is she saying to the police, what's your legal status in the UK, where are you from, is your girl friend a minor, have you done anything that could jeopardize your legal status?

In general your girlfriend's mother is a third party and has no impact on your legal standing in the UK, unless she has material evidence that would impact this. If she says "there is a foreign guy who wants to date my 25 year old daughter and I don't like this, so please arrest him", she will be ignored. If she says "there is a 30 year old foreign convicted drug dealer who wants to hook up with my 15 year old daughter, please help" they will almost certainly engage.

Comment: Your first line reminds me of *Henry IV, Part I*:  "GLENDOWER. I can call spirits from the vasty deep. / HOTSPUR. Why, so can I, or so can any man; But will they come when you do call for them?"

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Ha! Shakespeare was the original trolling pedant...

Comment: if the mom is reading your answer....now she dont need any lawyer now. lol